# Is there a limit of robots the game can handle?

Tags: factorio

I know there is no real limit about how many construction and logistic robots you can put in your factory.

However, there is probably a maximum number that will cause the game crash if reached. Did the dev team already talk about this or any other official source?

Comment: I read that someone had 32,000 robots.  Not sure what the actual limit is, but I would say it would be like any other game where if it reaches the point of an [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) it would break.  It looks like [Factorio is only 64 bit](https://www.factorio.com/blog/post/fff-158), making the integer overflow point at 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Comment: I would also say that by around 100,000 robots, your game would start to bog down unless you have some serious firepower hardware-wise. You would also have a lot of trouble trying to keep them all powered

Comment: @TimmyJim: If you want to get technical, Lua (the language the game is written in) has no integer-type.  Everything is double-precision float, so the max value before losing integer-precision is much lower than that, but the actual max value is much higher.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft interesting fact about the game, but yea it would definitely struggle at a high amount of robots.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Factorio is written primarily in C++ (as confirmed by the [developer](https://www.reddit.com/r/factorio/comments/6bzjmw/how_many_lines_of_what_language_of_code_is/)). Lua is used for scripting - basically mods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *(practically-reachable)* limit on how many robots you can have

The actual limiting-factor is how many robots the game can update each tic.  I've had games with 5000 robots out at once; many of them just floated in-place doing nothing for long periods, even though there was work to be done.

I'd guesstimate the limit was around 2000 active robots, but I have no data to back that up.

Comment: At the moment I have 9k logistic, and 10k construction, and when I get them to do a lot of building (say put down a load of concrete) my game drops to ~20fps when I'm in the construction area.

Comment: 0.15 does really feel much more snappy, the optimizations are working.  Proof: I had 8888 (exactly, even took a screenshot :D) construction bots out putting down landfill (there's a mod that enables landfill blueprints).  And they were snappy at it.  I do remember bots idling in thin air not doing anything for periods of time (of course, if you see this make sure they can do their job, if they can't they are also just hanging around)

Answer (score 4):

This is an old thread but I wanted to comment: I'm sitting at 105k logistic/4k construction. Usually about 70k are active but during peak I manage to use all 105k, power usage of about 10.5 GW at 70k and 12 when all are in use. I can confirm the limit (if one exists) is very,veryhigh.... the downside as you may have expected is the game runs at about 20 UPS or about 1/3 speed. Powering them isn't a big issue, blueprints of nuclear plants make increasing power production pretty easy: largest concern is finding points where they bunch up and i need to put more roboports, well that and the annoying slow speed the game functions at.